Q. If $C$ is the circle $|z|=1$ taken with positive orientation, evaluate $\displaystyle\oint_C\dfrac{e^{\sin z}}{z^4}dz$

$\displaystyle\oint_C\dfrac{e^{\sin z}}{z^4}dz$

my answer is coming out to be zero
I did it using the residue theorem, the residue is coming out to be zero at the point $z=0$
is this the correct way?
please give your answer and method

Hi, welcome to Math SE. I've improved your MathJax for the exponential, but please double-check whether you want the sine's argument to be $x$ (i.e. $\Re z$) as you stated rather than $z$.

@Manasvi use this result : Sum of all the residues + residue at infinity = 0

Note the only singularity in $|z|=1$ is at $z=0$, which is a pole of order 4. So Residue theorem gives the integral to be $$2\pi\times\dfrac{1}{3!}\left.\dfrac{d^3}{dz^3}e^{\sin z}\right|_{z=0}=\dfrac{\pi}{3}\left.(-e^{\sin\left(x\right)}\cos\left(x\right)(3\sin\left(x\right)-\cos^2\left(x\right)+1))\right|_{z=0}=0$$

To evaluate residue, it is enough to find a coefficient of $z^3$ of $e^{\sin z}$.
Since $\sin z\to 0$ under $z\to 0$,
$$\begin{align}
e^{\sin z}&\approx 1 + \sin z +\frac{\sin^2 z}{2} + \frac{\sin^3 z}{6} \\  
&\approx -\frac{z^3}{6} + \frac{1}{2}\left(0\right) + \frac{z^3}{6} \\ 
&= \cdots + 0z^3 + \cdots 
\end{align}$$
and this result shows our residue is zero directly.

We have $$e^{\sin z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\sin^nz\over n!}$$ Thus it suffices to consider two terms: $\sin z$ and $\sin^3z.$ We may omit $1$ and $\sin^2z$ as they are even functions. The integral of $(\sin z)/z^4$ is equal $(2\pi i)(-1/6),$ while the integral of $$(1/6)\sin^3z/z^4=(1/6)(\sin z/z)^3/z$$ is equal $(2\pi i)(1/6).$ Hence the result is equal $0,$ as in the OP.
